# Why does cv.glmnet give me different coefficient estimates even if I specify the same lambda?

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet

```
library(glmnet)
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)
x <- mvrnorm(n = 200, mu = c(0, 0, 0), Sigma = diag(3))
y <- rnorm(200, 4, 2)

mod1 <- cv.glmnet(x = x, y = y, lambda = c(0, 0.1), alpha = 1, standardize = FALSE)
mod2 <- cv.glmnet(x = x, y = y, lambda = NULL, alpha = 1, standardize = FALSE)
> coef(mod1, s = 0)
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     s1
(Intercept)  3.79180178
V1          -0.08206827
V2          -0.01223013
V3           0.16707533
> coef(mod2, s = 0)
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     s1
(Intercept)  3.79182932
V1          -0.08145740
V2          -0.01161146
V3           0.16631192
```

I'm running 2 LASSO models, `mod1` and `mod2`. The only difference in the function call is that I set `lambda = c(0, 0.1)` for the first model, and `lambda = NULL` for the second. Next, I extract the coefficient estimates and noticed that the coefficients are slightly different between the two models, even though I specifically specified `s=0`.

Perhaps the cross-validation is leading to the small discrepancy in the estimates. So I tried just the plain `glmnet` function, without any cross validation.

```
mod3 <- glmnet(x = x, y = y, lambda = c(0, 0.1), alpha = 1, standardize = FALSE)
mod4 <- glmnet(x = x, y = y, lambda = NULL, alpha = 1, standardize = FALSE)
> coef(mod3, s = 0)
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     s1
(Intercept)  3.79180178
V1          -0.08206827
V2          -0.01223013
V3           0.16707533
> coef(mod4, s = 0)
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     s1
(Intercept)  3.79182932
V1          -0.08145740
V2          -0.01161146
V3           0.16631192
```

However, there's still a discrepancy in the coefficient estimates even though I specifically set `s=0` when extracting the coefficient estimates through `coef(mod3, s = 0)` and `coef(mod4, s = 0)`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `cv.glmnet`? It is for finding the optimal $lambda$ via cross-validation. This value should then be plugged into `glmnet`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So by plugging in `lambda = c(0, 0.1`) and `lambda = NULL` into `mod3` and `mod4`, respectively, it's giving me 2 different model fits. I'm just wondering why using `coef(mod3, s = 0)` and `coef(mod4, s = 0)` gives me different estimates given that `s` is the value of lambda?

Comment: Because the amount of work in the two models is different, there's no reason to suppose that (even with the seed set the same before each is run) the same random folds will be generated.  For complete reproducibility, you need to generate the cross-validation folds once and for all and use them in both calls.